# ¿Como crear un div(html)dinamicamente?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Buen dia.No se si la pregunta que puse es algo que vayan a entender facilmente,asi que explicare.

Estuve pensando,cuando queremos que un menú se oculte o se muestre según el scroll se desplaza hacia arriba o hacia abajo,podemos hacerlo segun esta logica:

si scroll-top es mayor que un height determinado entonces muestrame el menú,pero si el scroll-top es menor que el height determinado entonces haz que el menú permanezca oculto.

Bien.

Este menú está hecho y diseñado en un código html y css,el cual está insertado en la misma pagina donde este se emplea.

Pero la pregunta es cómo hacer que este menú sea creado y recreado dinamicamente según el scroll baje y suba sin que este código(html)está insertado en la página.

Ojala puedan entender lo que quiero.Eso se me ocurrió hoy.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que lleves hasta el momento, tanto HTML como JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando javascript, y cambiando los estilos con `display: none` y `display: block` según corresponda a la situación que necesitas me parece que puedes lograr tu cometido.

Comment: Entiendo eso.Lo que quiero es crearlo(el código html) dinámicamente,no simplemente añadiendole eso.Me es facil hacerlo como dices.Y de la forma que dices lo único que tengo que hacer es poner el codigo del div en la pagina y añadirle display:none cuando el scroll este arriba y display:block cuando este abajo.Creo que hay algo que se puede hacer con la función Append.

Comment: Es correcto @Luis puedes crear un elemento con javascript, y buscar el nodo padre, del menú que quieres mostrar/ocultar, una vez lo hayas ubicado puedes utilizar la función `appendChild("tuHTMLDinámico")` y de esa forma puedes añadir HTML dinámicamente a tu web.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es **crearlo**, entonces necesitas considerar:
1.- Función para crear dinámicamente el menú, puedes considerar crearlo solo con `javascript`, o si necesitas información del servidor puedes incluir una petición `ajax`.
2.- Mostrar el Menú en pagina, podrías usar alguna función `jquery` para facilitarlo

```
//LLamar ArmarMenu o DestruirMenu segun el scroll
ArmarMenu:function(){
    //1. obteniendo informacion y armando menu
    $.ajax({
      url: "obtenerInformacionMenu.php",  
      success: function(data) {
           //1. armando menu
           var vhtml="";
           vhtml = vhtml+"<div>"+data.opcion[1]+"</div>"
           vhtml = vhtml+"<div>"+data.opcion[2]+"</div>"
           vhtml = vhtml+"<div>"+data.opcion[3]+"</div>"
           vhtml = vhtml+"<div>"+data.opcion[4]+"</div>"    
           //2. colocando menu en vista
           $('#ContenedorMenu').html(vhtml);
      }
    });
}

DestruirMenu:function(){
    $('#ContenedorMenu').html('');
}
```